# Make clicking a DOM <input> ref React.StrictMode compliant

Tags: reactjs

The component below is used to trigger opening a file input dialogue in desktop browsers and opening the camera on mobile devices. It is attached high in the component tree and is thus mounted once at startup, so the `input` DOM element is (in production) permanent. In `React.StrictMode` the component will trigger opening the file dialogue twice. *This is fine - I know what strict mode is,* but I am unsure *how* I can change the component to avoid triggering the input twice. We `click` the file input in the `shouldComponentUpdate` method and I guess there should be some kind of cleanup done to avoid this happening twice. The thing is, I thought we were doing this cleanup already, by triggering `closeCamera()`, which is dispatching an action that ends up changing state in our Redux store, so that eventually `props.openedBy` is set to `null`. This works fine in non-strict mode, so there is something I am missing ...

```
export class CameraTrigger extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  static defaultProps = {
    openedBy: undefined,
  }
  fileInputRef: React.Ref<any>

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.fileInputRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      lastOpenBy: undefined,
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Redux camera.openedBy state is changed to null immediately after displaying file selection window.
   *  Thanks to that we are sure that we have clear state regardless of the canceling or actual image selection.
   *  But we need to keep the information about opener to pass it to the saveImageFileAsObjectURL a short while later.
   */
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: Props, _state: State) {
    if (props.openedBy) {
      return {
        lastOpenBy: props.openedBy,
      }
    }

    return null
  }

  /* we never re-render the input button */
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Props, _nextState: State) {
    const { openedBy } = nextProps

    const ref = this.fileInputRef
    if (openedBy && ref) {
      ;(ref as any).current.click()
      this.props.closeCamera()
    }
    return false
  }

  clearInputBeforeNextUpload = (input: HTMLInputElement) => {
    input.value = ''
  }

  fileInputChanged = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const input = event.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement

    if (input.files && input.files.length) {
      const file = input.files[0]

      this.props.handleImageFile(file, this.state.lastOpenBy, this.state.lastEncounterId, this.state.lastConversationId)
      this.clearInputBeforeNextUpload(input)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        name="message-file-upload"
        type="file"
        accept={MimeTypeMap.JPEG}
        capture="environment"
        ref={this.fileInputRef}
        onChange={this.fileInputChanged}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
      />
    )
  }
}


type Props = {
  handleImageFile: Function
  closeCamera: Function
  openedBy?: string
}

type State = {
  lastOpenBy?: string
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `ref.current.click()` in  your `shouldComponentUpdate`? Surely that's something only the user should be initiating?

Comment: Just assume this is working as intended :) This is a hidden component that is controlled through the redux store. See the `style={{ display: 'none' }}`. That means that whenever we need to trigger an image upload in our app, we just dispatch an action that sets the `camera.openedBy` sub-state to something non-null and that will invoke a synthetic click on that input element, causing a native browser file input dialogue box to appear.

Comment: You're asking me to assume that the thing that is almost certainly causing more clicks than there should be, is working as intended. Start logging your `shouldComponentUpdate` arguments, because it sounds like you didn't account for the exact "when things should, or should not, click".

Comment: Sorry, that came out wrong. I meant _functionally_ working as intended. There is obviously a bug in the implementation that does not deal with the forced re-rendering done in strict mode, so there are bits I seem to be missing. I think I know what it is after reading up on the react docs, though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong and why through inspecting the React docs on pure vs impure functions.

In the older React docs on StrictMode, they have a section called ["Detecting Side Effects"](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) that talks about the render phase vs the commit phase, and that functions that are called in the render phase *should be pure*. Purity in this context means avoiding side-effects:

> Because the above methods might be called more than once, it’s important that they do not contain side-effects. Ignoring this rule can lead to a variety of problems,

and it lists the following functions as being called in the render phase

> Render phase lifecycles include the following class component methods:
>
> - constructor
> - componentWillMount (or UNSAFE_componentWillMount)
> - componentWillReceiveProps (or UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps)
> - componentWillUpdate (or UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate)
> - getDerivedStateFromProps
> - shouldComponentUpdate
> - render
> - setState updater functions (the first argument)

The (new) docs also say:

> To help you find accidentally impure code, Strict Mode calls some of your functions (only the ones that should be pure) twice in development

In the list that follows, it includes `shouldComponentUpdate`.

What this means is that my side-effect above, called in `shouldComponentUpdate` must be moved to another function that is called outside of the render phase. The correct (at least one way) method seems to be `componentDidUpdate`. As [the docs state](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Component#componentdidupdate):

> You can use it to manipulate the DOM after an update. This is also a common place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed). Typically, you’d use it together with componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount:

Simply moving the click-invoking to `componentDidUpdate` fixed the issue for me

and that removed the issue for me. Here's the diff

```
-  /* we never re-render the input button */
-  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Props, _nextState: State) {
-    const { openedBy } = nextProps
-
-    const ref = this.fileInputRef
-    if (openedBy && ref) {
-      ;(ref as any).current.click()
+  componentDidUpdate(_prevProps: Props, _nextState: State) {
+    const ref = this.fileInputRef as { current: HTMLInputElement }
+    if (this.props.openedBy && ref) {
+      ref.current.click()
       this.props.onTrigger()
     }
-    return false
   }
```